# Merge 2 images into 1, with blur

Tags: php, image

How can I merge 2 images in PHP and have a blur effect?

I need to make something like this http://www.bildites.lv/images/yzgc1puaci0nk1qeo0v.jpg (this image was created using photoshop).

Comment: PHP's [`Imagick` class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) should be able to do this, although you'll most likely need to generate an alpha mask if you can't use an image for one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use imagecopymerge() function.

For eg.

```
    <?php
    $dest = imagecreatefrompng('first.png');
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg('second.jpg');

    imagealphablending($dest, false);
    imagesavealpha($dest, true);

    imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 11, 11, 0, 0, 100, 43, 73); //See function parameter details

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($dest);

    imagedestroy($dest);
    imagedestroy($src);
    ?>
```

Comment: I haven't tried but imagecopymerge seems to be the right solution. It will help me later.